# I am using Searchview in Fragment and my data is not added in my New array Using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, error-handling, searchview

I am adding Searchview in Fragments and Menuitem is Inflated but when I click on Searchview Button and enter query Nothing Changes and my Data is not added.please help

here is the code
Answer should be in Kotlin

override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {

```
            temp.clear()    //this is my temp array

            var text=p0?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())

            if (text!!.isNotEmpty()){

        makeText(activity as Context,"working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            value.forEach {


                temp.add(it) //by this line data shoul add but not added

            }
            }else{

                makeText(activity as Context,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

              temp.clear()

              temp.addAll(value)

                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()


            }

            return true
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if user's input text is not empty, update data of your adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh your list.

change your first if scope to this:

```
if (text!!.isNotEmpty()) {
        makeText(activity as Context, "working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        value.forEach {
            temp.add(it) //by this line data shoul add but not added
        }
        recyclerView.adapter?.clear()
        recyclerView.adapter?.addAll(temp)
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: bro i alredy passed temp in adapter class,if i add your code then it says unresolved refrence,receiver type mismatch for these lines    recyclerView.adapter?.clear()
        recyclerView.adapter?.addAll(temp)

Comment: @Mohammad Bahadori improve your answer with recyclerView  context

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ramana please you help ne and tell me what to do here and how to get it's value in my temp array

Comment: @Shivamverma how did you define temp? where did you pass it to your adapter?

Comment: @Shivamverma in your first if scope you add data to your temp array but you don't recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged() why?

Comment: I passed it in my adapter class brackets like this.... adapter = adapter(activity as context,temp)

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanna say with this line ..but you don't recyclerView.adapter?. notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Do you have access to your adapter?

Comment: Post whole class that i can help you better.

Comment: Okay i do ...why don't you text me on telegram brother .. it'll be good for both of us here is my id @Shivam8860.i am waiting